# Find the Maclaurin Series of a function

Tags: analysis

How to find the Maclaurin series of the function $$f(x)=\frac{1}{(9-x^2)^2}$$
I guess we are gonna use derivatives but i have no idea how the final answer should be formed.

Comment: What is a Macklauren series?

Comment: He means maclaurin

Comment: Here is exactly how you can do it http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MaclaurinSeries.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\bf hint:$

(a)  use the binomial series $$(1-u)^{-2} = 1+\frac21 u+\frac{2 \cdot 3}{1 \cdot 2}u^2+ \frac{2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4}{1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3}u^3+ \cdots \tag 1$$

(b) $$\frac{1}{(9-x^2)^2} =\frac{1}{9^2(1-x^2/9)^2} = \frac1{81}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{9}\right)^{-2} \tag 2$$

Comment: I have made a slight edit, but please change it back if my edit is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

Start with the familiar geometric series: $\dfrac{1}{1-y} = \displaystyle\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}y^n$.

Next, differentiate both sides to get this series: $\dfrac{1}{(1-y)^2} = \displaystyle\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}ny^{n-1}$.

Now, what can you plug in for $y$ to make $\dfrac{1}{(1-y)^2}$ more like $\dfrac{1}{(9-x^2)^2}$?

Hint: $\dfrac{1}{(9-x^2)^2} = \dfrac{1}{9^2(1-\tfrac{x^2}{9})^2}$.

Comment: So it is all about knowing most common geometric series,no formulas and stuff at all?

Answer (score 0):

This answer uses ideas similar to the previous answers, but in a different order:

$\displaystyle\frac{1}{9-x^2}=\frac{\frac{1}{9}}{1-\frac{x^2}{9}}=\frac{1}{9}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{x^2}{9}\right)^{n}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{9^{n+1}}x^{2n},\;\;$ so differentiating gives

$\displaystyle\frac{2x}{(9-x^2)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2n}{9^{n+1}}x^{2n-1}$ and therefore $\displaystyle\frac{1}{(9-x^2)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{9^{n+1}}x^{2n-2}$.